# How to detect if some, but not all variables are equal to `null`

Tags: javascript, html

I have been having some problems with the `if` statement detecting if some but not all variables are equal to `null`
can someone help me with this?

```
 else if (co != 2 || o != 0 || d != 0 || e != 6)
                       
                       if (co == null && o == null && d == null && e == null) {
                          alert("foo") 
                      document.getElementById("e1").innerHTML += "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'><strong>Error</strong> You didn't enter anything.<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>"
                
                       } else if (co != null || o != null || d != null || e != null){
                           alert("bar")
                       document.getElementById("e1").innerHTML += "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'><strong>Nope.</strong> You entered the wrong code.<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>"
                       }
```

**PS: I copied the part of the JS** that’s why you see the else not actually having an if to start it ( also i wanted to keep things secret)

Comment: If you want to keep code secret, I suggest editing the variables and other names to something else, but without seeing a complete example, very difficult to help. This just looks like broken code...

Comment: @Taplar ```else if (co != null || o != null || d != null || e != null){
                           alert("bar")
                       document.getElementById("e1").innerHTML += "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'><strong>Nope.</strong> You entered the wrong code.<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>"
                       }```

Comment: @Taplar the `||` means ‘or’ not ‘and’

Comment: Missed that part.  Long day.  So the if part checks if they are all null.  If that fails, then the second one will be true if any of them are not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually Ended up changing the first part of the comparison to `===` instead `==` and i also realized that i put the value to  `’null’` (as a string) and actually not as a number therefore the 1st if was failing to successfully detect if `null=‘null’` there fore making the 2nd if appear true

Answer (score 4):

I'd put all these variables in an array and then use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check that some of them are null and some aren't:

```
const arr = [co, o, d, e];
if (arr.some(x => x === null) && arr.some(x => x !== null)) {
    alert("some are null and some aren't");
}
```

Comment: @Bruhh111 It was missing a closing parenthesis. Try again.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s40ug7wy/  Seems to work fine.

Comment: Please provide a test case of data that this solution doesn't work for

Comment: i’m using an editor that doesn’t have a built in console nor can i see errors, it marks things red for me if it is invalid, unless it makes the page blank

Comment: or it errors out and does not do anything and the rest of the JS is scuffed

Comment: I implemented this code and when i click the ‘enter’ button it does not alert me of what is in this code

Comment: "Does not work" does not mean that this logic does not work.  The issue could be else where.  As shown in the jsfiddle, this logic does work as expected.  Which is why I'm asking for a test case to show that it does not work.  Also if your editor is making it hard to find your data, you can always use your browser's debugger to set breakpoints, or logically set them with `debugger;` and find the data when you actually run the code.

Comment: i’m coding my site on mobile, therefore i cannot use Developer tools 